# django REST framework - allow only list of IP addresses to access?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to figure out the correct way to limit access to an `API` endpoint using `IP address`. I went through the docs, blocking is mentioned but limiting the call to `API` endpoint is not.

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: You mean you want to specify which IP can access a specific end-point, or what do you mean by "call"?

Comment: @WMRamadan, yes exactly. I want to specify which IP address can access a specific end-point.

Comment: You can use [django-iprestrict](https://django-iprestrict.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#:~:text=Django%20IPRestrict%20is%20an%20app,IP%20addresses%20from%20given%20countries.)   it's used to restrict access to your Django project by IP addresses The restriction can be for  sections of your API  it.

Answer (score 1):

Depending of your server architecture you can achieve it clearly programmatically, by:

```
def retrieve_user_ip(request):
    user_ip = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
    if user_ip:
        ip = user_ip.split(',')[-1] # According to Wiki, have to grab last element from HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR header
    else:
        ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR') # Basing on Django docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META
    return ip
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a custom permission to check if the ip address is in the list of safe ip addresses and set it in the DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES.

Something like:

```
class SafeIPPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if ip := request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'):
            ip = ip.split(',')[-1]r
        else:
            ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
        return ip IN settings.SAFE_IPS
```

And in your settings:

```
SAFE_IPS = [
    127.0.0.1,
    10.0.0.1,
    ...
]

...

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        ...
        'path.to.custom.permissions.SafeIPPermission',
        ...
    ]
}
```

Comment: This solution is not applicable to OP's question, in one of his comments he mentioned that he would like to limit queries from particular IPs to particular endpoints.